# Online PIM Needed: EverNote + Cozi =?

Tags: website, calendar, microsoft-onenote, evernote, pim

I am looking for an online solution with free-form note-taking ability like OneNote or EverNote, and also a robust calendaring system (tasks, repeating appts, notifications). Cozi has a great calendar but not much else... EverNote lasks the calendar side of things. Scrybe looks very promising on both fronts but is by invitation only.

Oh yeah... it should be free, too :D

Am I SOL?

Comment: well, you're SOL if you're waiting for Scrybe!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Springpad http://springpadit.com - we make it easy to collect, use and share content and data that you find on the web and we also provide calendaring integrated with gcal and other productivity features for task and project management.

Comment: The features look like their worth investigating, but I am already uneasy about springpad... I am on the features page using Firefox... When I mouseover the "Sign Up for Free" button I see a mailto: link with a subject of "Partners Inquiry", and when I actually click the button nothing happens. 

Using IE, the button moves across the page when I click it, and when I click it a 2nd time it opens my mail client...

http://screencast.com/t/MjY1ZDU0

http://screencast.com/t/YjQzY2MzZ

My search continues...

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention; we recently updated our website and obviously have some QA deficiencies we'll take care of asap. I hope you'll give the app a look - we welcome input and feedback.

Comment: All set now. Thanks again for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](http://www.google.com) seems to meet all of you requirements with Docs and Calendar, and free.

Docs: Not sure how free form you need it to be, but you can insert a drawing (which can be drawn online and not just an uploaded image), or insert a comment.

Calendar: has repeat tasks and reminders (popup or email notification.

I don't think the calendar and docs really integrate. You can't have a reminder on a doc or link the doc to a reminder, etc.

Colaboration and sharing are pluses.

And it's free.